# Зачем нужно смещение порядка в числах с плавающей точкой?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Зачем при хранении числа в формате с плавающей точкой к его порядку добавляют смещение?

Comment: Википедия говорит, чтобы удобней сравнивать float в побитовом представлении (смещение позволяет степень без знака хранить) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias